Unmanaged eth0 on Ubuntu 20.04
I’m having trouble setting a permanent static IP for eth0. I tried configuring it through Netplan and also made changes using vi to edit the network configuration files. I can manually assign the IP using the command sudo ip addr add 192.... dev eth0, but after a while, the IP changes, and I lose the static IP configuration.
